# parse xml to class using linq

Tags: .net, linq

i have a class that defines a request xml
i want to use linq to parse the xml to the class(later to do the opposite)
i am getting that req is null and in the function that returns the class all the proprieties " MidaClientID The name 'MidaClientID' does not exist in the current context   "

```
public class Request
    {
        public int MidaClientID { get; set; }

        public int Password { get; set; }

        public int CandNum { get; set; }

        public string CandFirstName { get; set; }

        public string CandLastName { get; set; }

        public int CandPhone1 { get; set; }

        public int CandPhone2 { get; set; }

        public int CandPhone3 { get; set; }

        public string CandAttach1 { get; set; }

        public string CandAttach2 { get; set; }

        public string CandAttach3 { get; set; }

        public int ClientNum { get; set; }

        public string ClientName { get; set; }

        public int ContactNum { get; set; }

        public string ContactFirstName { get; set; }

        public string ContactLastName { get; set; }

        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

        public int EventNum { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }

        public int QuestNum { get; set; }

    }


 [WebMethod]
        public void GetXml()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@".xml");
            List<Request> req = CreateRequest(doc);
        }


        public static List<Request> CreateRequest(XDocument input)
        {
            IEnumerable<Request> req = from r in input.Descendants("Request")
                                       select new Request()
                                       {
                                           //MidaClientID = (int)r.Attribute("MidaClientID"),
                                           MidaClientID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Element("MidaClientID").Value),
                                           Password = (int)r.Attribute("MidaClientPassword"),
                                           CandNum = (int)r.Attribute("CandNum"),
                                           CandFirstName = (string)r.Attribute("CandFirstName"),
                                           CandLastName = (string)r.Attribute("CandLastName"),
                                           CandPhone1 = (int)r.Attribute("CandPhone1"),
                                           CandPhone2 = (int)r.Attribute("CandPhone2"),
                                           CandPhone3 = (int)r.Attribute("CandPhone3"),
                                           CandAttach1 = (string)r.Attribute("CandAttach1"),
                                           CandAttach2 = (string)r.Attribute("CandAttach2"),
                                           CandAttach3 = (string)r.Attribute("CandAttach3"),
                                           ClientNum = (int)r.Attribute("ClientNum"),
                                           ClientName = (string)r.Attribute("ClientName"),
                                           ContactNum = (int)r.Attribute("ContactNum"),
                                           ContactFirstName = (string)r.Attribute("ContactFirstName"),
                                           ContactLastName = (string)r.Attribute("ContactLastName"),
                                           ContactEmail = (string)r.Attribute("ContactEmail"),
                                           EventNum = (int)r.Attribute("EventNum"),
                                           EventDate = (DateTime)r.Attribute("EventDate"),
                                           EventTime = (DateTime)r.Attribute("EventTime"),
                                           QuestNum = (int)r.Attribute("QuestNum")
                                       };
            return new List<Request> { };
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting null is because you are returning new instance of list.

```
return new List<Request> { };
```

Can you replace the above line of code to

```
return req;
```

As shown in the below code.

```
public static List<Request> CreateRequest(XDocument input)
        {
            IEnumerable<Request> req = from r in input.Descendants("Request")
                                       select new Request()
                                       {
                                           //MidaClientID = (int)r.Attribute("MidaClientID"),
                                           MidaClientID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Element("MidaClientID").Value),
                                           Password = (int)r.Attribute("MidaClientPassword"),
                                           CandNum = (int)r.Attribute("CandNum"),
                                           CandFirstName = (string)r.Attribute("CandFirstName"),
                                           CandLastName = (string)r.Attribute("CandLastName"),
                                           CandPhone1 = (int)r.Attribute("CandPhone1"),
                                           CandPhone2 = (int)r.Attribute("CandPhone2"),
                                           CandPhone3 = (int)r.Attribute("CandPhone3"),
                                           CandAttach1 = (string)r.Attribute("CandAttach1"),
                                           CandAttach2 = (string)r.Attribute("CandAttach2"),
                                           CandAttach3 = (string)r.Attribute("CandAttach3"),
                                           ClientNum = (int)r.Attribute("ClientNum"),
                                           ClientName = (string)r.Attribute("ClientName"),
                                           ContactNum = (int)r.Attribute("ContactNum"),
                                           ContactFirstName = (string)r.Attribute("ContactFirstName"),
                                           ContactLastName = (string)r.Attribute("ContactLastName"),
                                           ContactEmail = (string)r.Attribute("ContactEmail"),
                                           EventNum = (int)r.Attribute("EventNum"),
                                           EventDate = (DateTime)r.Attribute("EventDate"),
                                           EventTime = (DateTime)r.Attribute("EventTime"),
                                           QuestNum = (int)r.Attribute("QuestNum")
                                       };
            return req;
```

}

Comment: The problem is that all of the properties from the class request that i am trying to insert values to them are not existing .this is my main problam

Comment: this problem is bugging me for the second day,if i can see the properties that in the class why i am getting that they are not defined and i can`t set values into properties.

Comment: Can you change all the instances of your class to have its namespace included? Example. Change List<Request> to List<YourNameSpace.Request>

Comment: The problem solved, i didn't insert properly values into the date time property

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by serializing the object.

"Serialization is the process of taking the state of an object and persisting it in some fashion. The Microsoft .NET Framework includes powerful objects that can serialize any object to XML. The System.Xml.Serialization namespace provides this capability."

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: Thank you for the response,this will be very good for my second part,i tried like the example and it works fine.